# Duplicate rows in MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason every once in a while my code will enter data into the database twice. I have changed my code and made some tweaks but have not had any luck. I know I must be over looking something I just don't know what.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "******", "******", "******");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$conpo = new mysqli("localhost", "******", "******", "******");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$resultpo = mysqli_query($conpo, "SELECT * FROM fpo ORDER BY ponum DESC LIMIT 1");

while ($rowp = mysqli_fetch_array($resultpo)) {
    $po = $rowp['ponum'];
    $ponum = ++$po;
}

$date = $_POST['date'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$vin = $_POST['stk_vin'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$empnum = $_POST['emp'];
$mananger = $_POST['mananger'];
$accnum = $_POST['acc'];
$store_location = $_POST['store'];
$borr = $_POST['borrowed'];
$oldid = $_POST['oldid'];

mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO fpo (" .
    "`ponum`, `date`, `to`, `time`, `vin`, `reason`, `amount`, `empnum`, `mananger`, `accnum`, `store_location`, `borr`" .
    ") VALUES (" .
    "'$ponum', '$date', '$to', '$time', '$vin', '$reason', '$amount', '$empnum', '$mananger', '$accnum', '$store_location', '$borr'" .
    ")");
?>
```

Here is the html forum page.

```
<form action="print.php" method="POST" name="form1" id="form1">
     <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" style="width:700px">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td height="19" colspan="2" valign="middle" class="to" style="width:450px" ><div class="logo"></div></td>
           <td width="95" rowspan="2" valign="bottom"><div class="date">Date:
             <label>
               <input name="date" type="text" readonly id="date" value="07/15/2015" size="10" />
             </label>
           </div></td>
           <td width="106" rowspan="2" valign="bottom" class="po" style="width:100px" ><div class="date">PO: <span id="sprytextfield3">
             <label>
                              <input name="po" readonly  type="text" value="14739" />
               <input type="hidden" name="oldid" value="11810">
              </label>
             <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></div></td>
</tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="20" colspan="2" valign="middle" class="to" style="width:450px" ><div class="toheader">To: <span id="spryselect1">
             <label>
               <select name="to" id="to">
                 <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select One</option>
                                  <option value="1">Kum-N-Go</option>
                                 </select>
              </label>
             <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span>
             <input name="time" type="hidden" id="time" value="
                11:13:33                ">
           </div></td>
</tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="2" style="height:125px" ><b> Reason For Gas Ticket: </b> <br>
             <span id="spryselect2">
               <label>
                 <select name="reason" id="reason">


              <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select One</option>
                   <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
                   <option value="Auction">Auction</option>
                 </select>
               </label>
               <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Required</span></span><br>
               <br>
Car Borrowed From Another Dealership? <br>
<span id="spryselect3">
<label>
  <select name="borrowed" id="borrowed">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select One</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</label>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span><br></td>
           <td><b>stk/vin/RO#:</b><br>
             <span id="sprytextfield2">
               <label>
                 <input name="stk_vin" type="text" id="stk_vin" onclick="return stk()" size="12" />
               </label>
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br />
                 Stock or Vin .</span></span></td>
           <td align="center"><b> Amount<br>
             <div class="money"><span id="spryselect5">
               <label><b>
                 <select name="amount" id="amount">
                   <option value="5.00" selected="selected">5.00</option>
                   <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
                   <option value="2.00">2.00</option>
                   <option value="3.00">3.00</option>
                   <option value="4.00">4.00</option>
                   <option value="5.00">5.00</option>
                   <option value="6.00">6.00</option>
                   <option value="7.00">7.00</option>
                   <option value="8.00">8.00</option>
                   <option value="9.00">9.00</option>
                   <option value="10.00">10.00</option>

                 </select>
               </b></label>
               <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></div>
</b></td>
</tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="257">Employee Requesting Po:<span id="spryselect9">
             <label>
               <select name="emp" id="acc">
                 <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select One</option>

                                      <option value="5223">5223</option>
                                    </optgroup>

               </select>
             </label>
             <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Required</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Required</span></span></td>
           <td width="219">Acc #:<span id="spryselect4">
             <label>
               <select name="acc" id="acc">
                 <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select One</option>
                 <option value="51">Sales</option>
                 <option value="52">Services</option>
                 <option value="53">Parts</option>
                 <option value="FI">F&amp;I</option>
               </select>
             </label>
             <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Required</span></span></td>
           <td colspan="2" align="right"><label> Mananger:
             <input name="mananger" onclick="return getfoc()" type="text" id="mananger" size="12" readonly />
           </label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>Store: <span id="spryselect6">
             <label>
               <select name="store" id="store">
                 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
                 <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
                 <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
                 <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
               </select>
             </label>
             <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Required</span></span></td>
           <td colspan="2" align="right"><div id="btn"> </div>
             <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

    function GetValueFromChild(myVal)

    {

document.getElementById('mananger').value = myVal;
document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = '<input type="submit" id="register" value="Print Ticket" />';


    }

             </script></td>
         </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </form>
```

Comment: are you 100% sure this script cant be triggerd twice if somebody clicked on a button really quick? because that would normally be the reason of double entries..... also is this script selecting and then re-entering the same data in the same table AGAIN ???? i'm not sure i'm understanding what your doing here.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing how the data is posted to this script. Ajax, form on same page, form on different page? show the relevant code. Also you're wide open to sql injection

Comment: This code is susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Sorry, The forum is on hom.php and its just a standard HTML forum that uses the POST action to this page. I have played with pressing the button more then once before is submits and it doesn't double submit. how ever i have done it where i click it one time and it double submits.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not doing atomic operation. Lets assume the below flow:

SELECT1 -> SELECT2-> INSERT1-> INSERT2

How are avoid this - no synchronization or locking. You can avoid this with few options.

1. Use a lock before entering this block and free once insert is done( in PHP). This can be based on file lock or memcache lock
2. You can add an index on the column you want to keep unique say, (ponum, from, to). Instead of using `INSERT`, you can use `INSERT IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your users are clicking the submit button twice I had this issue before I fixed it using jquery's validator such as following.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form1").validate({submitHandler: function(form) {if (!this.beenSubmitted)           {this.beenSubmitted = true;form.submit();}  }});
  });
```